# Evitar autenticación cuadro de diálogo de JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy ejecutando un applet y al momento de llamarlo, me sale un cuadro de diálogo de `Java` pidiéndome los datos de usuario y clave, si los pongo funciona perfecto, este cuadro de diálogo tiene una opción que es guardar la contraseña en la lista de contraseñas, éstas se guardan en el applocal del usuario con el nombre auth.dat.

Lo que hice para poder ejecutarlo fue tomar ese archivo que me genero `Java` y ponerlo en el momento antes de la ejecución, de esta forma ya tiene las credenciales que necesita y se ejecuta sin problemas, esto lo ejecuto en una máquina de `windows 7` con `Java 7` y funciona perfecto, cuando lo implemento en otra máquina que es un `windows server 2008` copio el archivo pero `Java` me lo sobrescribe y por ende pierde las credenciales y vuelve a salir el cuadro de diálogo.

¿Saben cómo y dónde se configura esto para que tome lo que tiene ahí y no me sobrescriba el archivo?

Answer (score 1):

Deberías buscar una alternativa como JavaFx,Java web start, o incluso web service, jsp o servlets porque el único navegador que soporta applets en este momento es firefox, y firefox ha anunciado que dejará de soportar tecnologías NPAPI como los applets al finalizar 2016, ya que representan un problema de seguridad. Esa es la misma razón por la que otros navegadores ya no soportan applets.
[Aqui](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/) esta la información.